# Erro após atualizar o nome do package (o app não roda)

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu renomeie o nome do meu package e após o meu aplicativo não roda mais. Eu atualizei o nome em todos os arquivos que são necessários (AndroidManifest no debug, main e profile e o kotlin) mas ele não roda de jeito nenhum. Quando clico em run ele vai até a parte Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...  e ai depois a splash screen do app abre e fecha rapidamente. O app fica "instalado" (tanto no emulador quanto em um dispositivo real) mas quando tento abrir a splash screen abre e fecha rapidamente de novo. O que eu faço?? Estou tentando resolver esse problema ja tem uma semana seguindo algumas repostas daqui e infelizmente não consigo.

Esse é o meu flutter doctor (Flutter e dart plugin estão instalados corretamente, este é apenas um bug da versão)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E já viu o log de erro do Logcat?

Comment: 2021-06-19 17:21:31.907 1962-1962/com.julis.app_vestibular E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.julis.app_vestibular, PID: 1962
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.julis.app_vestibular/com.example.br.com.app_vestibular.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.br.com.app_vestibular.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.julis.app_vestibular-UwzTbrEsaENu5YLr4zxImg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.julis.app_vestibular-

Comment: aparece o seguinte erro

Comment: Dê um flutter clean para se certificar que não é cache, o que eu acho que não seja. Mas o próprio log do erro está lhe informando que você não alterou em todos os lugares necessários: com.julis.app_vestibular <> com.example.br.com.app_vestibular.

Comment: Eu já havia dado um flutter clean antes para ver se funcionava, mas realmente não é isso. Vendo esse erro no logcat parece que é algo que não foi alterado no MainActivity, só que ao olhar o arquivo parece tudo certo

Comment: Para testar de verdade no Android Studio, apague o device e recrie. Veja [aqui](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) como fazer. Caso não funcione, com certeza ainda falta fazer alguma coisa na app. Veja se este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694153/changing-the-project-name) ajuda

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso, o erro foi solucionado quando alterei o nome do package no folder "kotlin" em /app/src/main/kotlin. Verifique se os nomes dos packages são os mesmos. Obs.: O nome do 'package' no file MainActivity dentro do kotlin também de ser alerado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).